# How to import RoR project to Netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

I have very simple (in fact empty ) project which i have created by **rails new MyProject** command from command-line. So, i want to import it to NetBeans IDE. I click "new project" -> "RoR" -> "from existing source", select Ruby 1.9.2 (instead of embedded JRuby) in the wizard form. After that i have got errors [see the picture below]: [image]
So.. i click OK. And then try to run the RoR application from NetBeans clicking on the run-button and i got the following error in the log-panel:

```
/home/ses/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)
```

So how to handle these two problems?

*p.s. my application is working when i launch it from the console.
i use ruby-1.9.2 and RoR 3.0 and Netbeans 6.9.1 and Ubuntu 10.10*

and, replying the comment to my question. **yes**, i performed following commands:

```
bundle install

Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.15) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.7) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using mysql2 (0.2.6) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 

bundle pack
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.3) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.13) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.24) 
Using actionpack (3.0.3) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.15) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.3) 
Using arel (2.0.7) 
Using activerecord (3.0.3) 
Using activeresource (3.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.0.10) 
Using mysql2 (0.2.6) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.0.3) 
Using rails (3.0.3) 
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
```

and following this page http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRubyRakeFetchingFailed
i did `rake -D`

Comment: have your tried "bunlde install" and "bundle pack" in ur project dir via console?

Comment: i figured out the problem. in order to be everything ok i configured the platform for ruby (in nb-form window), i had right path to my gems (by default NB detected wrong path to its).

Comment: Just a heads up, netbeans is no longer going to support ruby in the next version. They're stopping development. Try rubymine, it's only $29 now.

Answer (score 2):

this is what I did to get it working (had same problem):

New project > with existing sources
Tools > Ruby Platforms > select Ruby 1.9.2-p136 > Gem Manager > New Gems > rails > install
restart netbeans
open project (if it's not already opened) and right click > bundler > install
run

first of all, what you should't do is expect the debugger to work. because it's not going to work on netbeans, not on rails 3 (there are some hacks but they have problems).
secondly, [Ruby on Rails Support Discontinued in NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1507.html). I loved the way Netbeans worked with rails 2.x, but I migrated to RubyMine because of it's support for Rails 3

hope this helps

Comment: http://http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteWorthy#Rails_3_Support

it seems some support of RoR are present in NB.